# How to DataBind a TextBox to a particular index in a List<>

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, data-binding

I have standard databindings setup for all my TextBoxes to an Object like this:

```
TextBoxMenuID.DataBindings.Add("Text", _selectedObject, "ID");
```

And I want to bind some of my TextBoxes to a List<> index within that Object like this:

```
TextBoxQ1.DataBindings.Add("Text", _selectedObject._qList[0].QuestionString, null);
```

The binding isn't working this way. Any ideas how to go about this kind of binding?

Thanks,
SleffTheRed

Comment: How does it work if you use the first snippet you provided but in the code you also assign to selectedObject the object of the item in position 0 of your list you used in the second snippet?

Comment: How am I assigning the item in position 0 of the list to the selected object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Credit to Mitja for the code, but to change the index just add []'s:

```
list = new List<Person>();
list.Add(new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Name 1", Age = 21 });
list.Add(new Person { ID = 2, Name = "Name 2", Age = 28 });
list.Add(new Person { ID = 3, Name = "Name 3", Age = 44 });

textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list[0], "Name", false));
textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list[1], "Name", false));
textBox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list[2], "Name", false));

internal class Person
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 6):

If you are using a generic list as a collection of data, then you can do it like:

```
List<Person> list;
public Form1()
{
   InitializeComponent();
   list = new List<Person>();
   list.Add(new Person { ID = 1, Name = "Name 1", Age = 21 });
   list.Add(new Person { ID = 2, Name = "Name 2", Age = 28 });

   textBox1.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list, "ID", false));
   textBox2.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list, "Name", false));
   textBox3.DataBindings.Add(new Binding("Text", list, "Age", false));
}

internal class Person
{
   public int ID { get; set; }
   public string Name { get; set; }
   public int Age { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Yes Mitja, thanks for the answer, but Davide is right. I actually need the 3 text boxes you used as an example to bind to: textBox1 -> bound to "Name 1", textBox2 -> bound to "Name 2" for example.

Comment: +1 so I could copy your code Mitja, but Sleff, see the code I pasted up top to do that, its very simple.